# smallest splitting field and Galois expansion

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, semidirect-product

Let$K$ be the smallest splitting field $X^5-7$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then how many intermediate fields of $K$ which is Galois expansion of $\mathbb{Q}$.

I know $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=[K:\mathbb{Q}(7^{\frac{1}{5}})][\mathbb{Q}(7^{\frac{1}{5}}):\mathbb{Q}]=20$ by translation theorem.
I guess Galois group $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is $\mathbb{Z}/{5\mathbb{Z}} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/{4\mathbb{Z}}$.But I can't prove and I don't know how to find subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/{5\mathbb{Z}} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/{4\mathbb{Z}}$.

Answer (score 1):

The Galois group is indeed isomorphic to
$$
\mathbb{Z}/5 \rtimes (\mathbb{Z}/5)^{\times}\cong \mathbb{Z}/5 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/4,
$$

see here:

[Computing the Galois group of polynomials $x^n-a \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204552/computing-the-galois-group-of-polynomials-xn-a-in-mathbbqx).

Also the subgroups of such semidirect products have been determined at this site, e.g., here:

[Subgroups of the Semi-Direct Product $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{7Z} \rtimes (\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{7Z})^{\times}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741572/subgroups-of-the-semi-direct-product-mathbbz-mathbb7z-rtimes-mathbbz?rq=1)